# OData feed to SharePoint List

Tags: odata

Is it possible to import/update data from an OData feed into a SharePoint list?

Right now I'm using the feed with an excel file + webpart for display, but the ability to manage this on a SharePoint list will be an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an External List using that feed.

First create an External Content source using SharePoint Designer. Then use that to create the List.